# How to display a web site web from a computer via SSH tunnel opposite?

Tags: linux, browser, ssh

I have a computer name "YELLOW" with internet 3g. The internet is behind a NAT, and a variable IP address. That's why I can not get the computer "YELLOW" normally connectivities of the laptop. Fortunately, I have bought the server and your computer "YELLOW" to connect to this server via SSH tunnel.

> **Scheme:** [[Computer "YELLOW" & SSH]] <---> [[Server & SSH]] <--->
>   [[Laptop & Putty]]

It works well.

1. The road is complicated, because the first run Putty and connect to the server. Later, from the server I am connecting to a computer "YELLOW". Can it be simplified?
2. On the computer "YELLOW" I have a web server and website. How do I display it on a laptop? My colleagues also have laptops, but they have installed Putty. Is it possible to do so, in order to be able to view this page on their laptops, which is located on your computer "YELLOW"? It may be enough to set a proxy server and Socket5, and then enter the web address www.some-sort-of-domain.-xx/yellow and displays a page located on your computer "Yellow"?

> **Scheme:** [[Computer "YELLOW" & SSH & server www + page]] <---> [[Server
>   & SSH + domain www.some-sort-of-domain.-xx/]] <---> [[Laptop
>   [1...5...n] & browser (no putty, no proxy, etc.)]]

Answer (score 0):

using ssh : if you can connect via ssh to a host (any host) that can access the www server, then you can use SSH tunneling, to allow local machines do this (you'll have to dedicate local port(s) to that other computer could connect to... *if* your local firewall allows it)

I am not sure I understood the setting : here is what I think I understood

- the page to be viewed is on "Yellow"
- you access Yellow via : first ssh from "Laptop1" to "Server", and then from "Server" to "Yellow"
- other laptops could access Laptop1 on specific ports (that you'll need to open access to, on Laptop1, by setting specific ports in Laptop1's firewall. Let's say it will be ports 2080 and 2443, for example.

If so:

- on the first ssh (Laptop1 to Server), add a Tunnel that forward Local port (local in Laptop1) "2080" to Server's port "3080" for example. Add another Tunnel that forward Local "2443" to Server's "3443".
- then on the 2nd ssh (Server to Yellow), add a Tunnel that forward Server port 3080 to Yellow port 80 (if using http on Yellow). And another forwarding Server port 3443 to Yellow port 443 (if https)  (or other ports if you are not using default ports for the webserver on Yellow)

Then test, on Laptop1 :

`http://localhost:2080/`  or   `https://localhost:2443/`

This should access the webserver on Yellow  (you may need to specify an url, such as : `http://localhost:2080/path/to/something.php` )

If it is not working : make sure (in putty, and in each hop's servers) that port forwarding is enabled.

Once you can connect from Laptop1 using that local port, you can also give access to that local port to other laptops (by editing Laptop1 firewall). And you'll need to click (in Laptop1's Putty) the SSH option "Local ports accept connections from other hosts" (otherwise, by default, Putty only allow your local machine to use the 2080 and 2443 ports)